# Outlook email info autofilled into Sharepoint list

Tags: outlook, flow

I want to copy email data into a SharePoint list. User will select which e-mail s/he wants to add and e-mail will be copied into a multi-line text box in sharepoint.  Also, e-mail attachments data will be copied automatically. How can I do this? Is there a way to intelligently convert and autofill email info with attachments into sharepoint? can we do this with microsoft flow and if so can someone make me a template?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you can configure a list for receiving emails, the one I have used is Announcements list template on SP 2013. Then you create a workflow that will parse the content of the email. Whit this type of implementation you will need to define a format to let your users know how they should send the information so your workflow can parse it and add it the desired fields and yet this will need validations, trim or cast. So far, I don't know any tool that does this that automatically.

Some documentation:
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Enable-incoming-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-dcaf44a0-1d9b-451a-84c7-6c52e7db908e